# Is it possible to filter and count at the same time in grep?

Tags: awk, grep

I have a file with several million lines (Apple's EPF)
What I need is to filter this using few search terms, but at the same time I need the number of matched lines to put in last row of output file.
I thought of course about two runs - one that filter, and another that counts but that doesn't look like optimal solution because one filter can take few minutes.

for now I am testing something like this:

```
grep -f filtrowanie application_price_old > appprice_temp
perl -i -pe 's/#recordsWritten\:\d{7,8}/#recordsWritten:`grep -e '^\d' -c 
appprice_temp`/ appprice_temp
```

Comment: Please post sample Input_file and expected sample output too in code tags.

Comment: and include your best attempt to solve the problem. Do you know about `grep -c` (read the `man grep` to see other possibilities built in).

Comment: This count the lines with the word that you are searching: `cat filename | grep word_to_search | wc -l`

Comment: Just because the filter took minutes, doesn't mean that counting its output will. If you remove 90% of several million, the remainder can be counted in a very short time.

Comment: @Pentux. Barring the files that OP wants to write to along the way and some necessary flags to `grep`, that should do the trick.

Comment: Is there some reason you need to use `grep`?  If it's a simple pattern you are looking for, it's probably fine to do something like `awk '/pattern/ {count++; print} END {print count}`

Comment: @Pentux wins the dubious award of combining a useless `cat` with a [useless `wc`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#wc). I think you mean `grep -c word_to_search filename` but of course, the OP clearly already knows how to do that.

Comment: @tripleee thank you for the award. Now is obviously what the OP wants because he's edited the post. I learnt the `grep -c`, for me have been useful this post.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the text and code you provided in your question, this is probably what you're looking for:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR { regexps[$0]; next }
    {
        for (regexp in regexps) {
            if ($0 ~ regexp) {
                print
                cnt++
                next
            }
        }
    }
    END {
        print "#recordsWritten:" cnt+0
    }
' filtrowanie application_price_old > appprice_temp
```

If that's not what you need then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide concise, testable sample input and expected output.